# How to make a production build of Node.js express API

Tags: node.js, express, build, production

I have a React.JS frontend and Node.js API built with express. I want to make a production build of express API like we do in React.js using a command like `npm run build`. How can I achieve this? I know there is heroku for easy production deployments but I am using a VPS here.

Thanks :)

Comment: Node.js is a javascript runtime that executes javascript in servers, so it cannot be built like the browser apps. However, you might want to use a process manager like [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/), as well as following [this](http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#production-best-practices-performance-and-reliability) express guide for production best practices

Comment: Are you using something like babel or typescript in your node app that requires building? You may not need to build anything and your code is ready to be deployed.